# Index of rows in data frame A, which is contained in data frame B

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, row

I have two data frames, A and B.

```
a1 <- c(12, 12, 12, 23, 23, 23, 34, 34, 34)
a2 <- c(1, 2, 3 , 2, 4 , 5 , 2 , 3 , 4)
A <- as.data.frame(cbind(a1, a2))

b1 <- c(12, 23, 34)
b2 <- c(1, 2, 2)
B <- as.data.frame(cbind(b1, b2))

> A
  a1 a2
1 12  1
2 12  2
3 12  3
4 23  2
5 23  4
6 23  5
7 34  2
8 34  3
9 34  4
> B
  b1 b2
1 12  1
2 23  2
3 34  2
```

Basically, B contains the rows in A, with the lowest values of a2 for each unique a1.

What I need to do is simple. Find the row indexes (or row numbers?) lets call this for index.vector, such that A[index.vector, ] equals B.

For this particular problem, there will be only one solution, because for each unique value of a1, there is no values in a2 that are the same.

The faster the routine, the better. Need to apply this on data frames with anywhere between 500 and millions of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make sure my data is ordered first (in your example the data is ordered correctly, but I guess this might not always be the case), then use `match` which returns the index of the first match of it's first argument in it's second argument (or `NA` if there is no match).

```
A <- A[ order( A$a1 , A$a2 ) , ]
A
#  a1 a2
#1 12  1
#2 12  2
#3 12  3
#4 23  2
#5 23  4
#6 23  5
#7 34  2
#8 34  3
#9 34  4

#  Get row indices for required values
match( B$b1 , A$a1 )
[1] 1 4 7
```

And here is a data.table solution which should be *far* faster for large tables

```
require(data.table)
A <- data.table( A )
B <- data.table( B )

#  Use setkeyv to order the tables by the values in the first column, then the second column
setkeyv( A , c("a1","a2") )
setkeyv( B , c("b1","b2") )

#  Create a new column that is the row index of A
A[ , ID:=(1:nrow(A)) ]

#  Join A and B on the key columns (this works because you have unique values in your second column for each grouping of the first), giving the relevant ID
A[B]
#   a1 a2 ID
#1: 12  1  1
#2: 23  2  4
#3: 34  2  7
```

Comment: @user2463819 I added a data.table solution which will be faster for large data.frames